# Is there a simple way to make matplotlib text boxes float like the legend does by default?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, legend

I'm able to code what I want after extensively reading the matplotlib docs, but I'm curious if there's a simpler solution. I'll add the relevant code below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

li_green = "#6BA755"
li_grey = "#D7D7D7" # rgb hex-code for the grey outline around the legend box
ax.plot(data_date, cumsum_income, ".-", label="Raw")
ax.plot(data_date, exp_func(months, *popt), label="Fit", color=li_green)

str_fit_eqn = '\n'.join(("Fit Equation:",
                         r"%.2f$e^{%.2fx}$%.2f" % (popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]),
                         r"$R^2$= %.2f" % (r_squared,)))
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor="white", edgecolor=li_grey) # these are the text box parameters
anchored_text = AnchoredText(str_fit_eqn, loc=4, frameon=False, prop=dict(bbox=props))
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)

ax.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

Another way to phrase my question, is there a single parameter that would accomplish this text box outline or should I use something else than AnchoredText?

[image]